# Is there any way to make the Python garbage collection deterministic?

Tags: python, memory

So I have the following problem:

I want to measure the memory complexity of a function and I am using the following code. For memory measurement the module memory_profiler is used. Apparently, this module is not subtracting already allocated memory automatically, so I tried to subtract allocated memory. Problem seemingly is, that even when I invoke the garbage collector manually (and mark all relevant variables with del), memory gets freed while I am trying to measure the consumption of the function. This destroys the measurement. Is there any way to work around this problem and prevent the garbage collection from interfering?

```
for key in datasets.keys():
        
        stats[key] = {"Runtime" : None, "Memory" : None}

        del data
        
        del memory
        
        del start
        
        del end
        
        del initialMem
        
        gc.collect()

        data =  datasets[key]["Train"]["X"].iloc[datasets[key]["Train"]["subset"],:].reset_index(drop=True)

# start of measurement
        
        initialMem = memory_usage(-1)
        
        start = time.time()

        memory = memory_usage((buildDistanceMatrix,(data, distanceMetric)))

        end = time.time()

        stats[key]["Runtime"] = end - start
            
        stats[key]["Memory"] = max(memory) - max(initialMem)
```

Comment: take a look at the [`gc` (Garbage Collector interface) module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html), it seems to allow disabling automatic garbage collection which is what I understand you want

Comment: Thank you, that should do the work!